# Cheapest way to access and modify a struct

Tags: solidity

I am using solidity 0.8.10.

In my contract I have a state variable struct:

```
struct Product {
    uint id_prod;
    address payable producer_addr;
    address payable owner_addr;
    bool onSale;
    }
```

and a state variable array of products:

```
Product[] public ProductList;
```

and a function that allows to modify the attributes of the product. Nothing really complex.

Considering the cost in deploying and using the contract, I think there are two ways of changing the attributes of the product.

**Solution 1**, by using a storage variable:

```
Product storage _product = ProductList[_id_product];
_product.owner_addr = payable(msg.sender);
_product.onSale = false;
```

**Solution 2**, without a storage variable:

```
ProductList[_id_product].owner_addr = payable(msg.sender);
ProductList[_id_product].onSale = false;
```

Which solution is the cheapest, cleanest, most advisable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the numbers:

I deployed a similar contract to yours and called each function. Although implementations can vary,

The transaction costs were:

- Solution 1: `28785 gas`
- Solution 2: `28985 gas`

And, deployment costs were:

- Solution 1: `275180`
- Solution 2: `281006`

**Solution 2** uses  `2 sload` and  `2 sstore` operations. It loads from storage each time you want to access the data, and writes to storage each time you assign new value.

**Solution 1** uses a storage pointer. So we `sload` only once and than use the reference.

You can see from the transaction cost differences, that the difference is `200 gas` and a single `sload` operation uses `200 gas` as well.

So, both in terms of readability(imho), transaction cost and deployment cost; solution 1 was more efficient. And the more fields you use, the more efficient the solution 1 will become.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. How did you calculate the costs? I do not find the information in remix. Do you find it in ganache?

Comment: deployed the contract, called the function, looked at the gas cost

Comment: I see transaction cost in ganache for function writing onto the blockchain. What about calling public variables and readonly functions?